Next Auth V5 how to get JWT token
As I understand it, next auth creates a JWT token itself, but I don't understand how to get it
Here is the configuration of the auth.ts file
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import axios from "axios";

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  },
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    Credentials({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        try {
          const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login', {
            email: credentials.email,
            password: credentials.password,
          });

          const user = res.data;
          
          if (user) {
            return user;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Login error:", error);
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account }) {
      if (account?.provider === 'google') {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/google-signin', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            idToken: account.id_token, 
          }),
        });

        if (!res.ok) {
          console.error("Failed to create user");
          return false;
        }

        const userData = await res.json();
        if (userData && userData.role) {
          user.role = userData.role;
        }
      }
      return true;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return {...token, ...user};
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token as any;
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
});

The session object after authentication looks like this
{
  user: {
    name: 'testuser',
    email: 'testuser@test.com',
    picture: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocJ-Cr0XVdUf5HfHhOvsVZuC3ShYaNPWv-cAjJTRs5mhoF91cw=s96-c',
    sub: '66a8c9b102c0bd61a0a65639',
    id: '66a8c9b102c0bd61a0a65639',
    role: 'user',
    image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocJ-Cr0XVdUf5HfHhOvsVZuC3ShYaNPWv-cAjJTRs5mhoF91cw=s96-c',
    iat: 1722577679,
    exp: 1725169679,
    jti: '17493ea5-a58d-4a1c-ac3a-102039df7856'
  },
  expires: '2024-09-01T05:48:00.555Z'
}

And as you can see there is no token here, which is why I can't use it in headers
I have the server part of the application written in Node js and Express and there are secure routes that require authorization (verification is carried out using a JWT token)
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

const jwtSecretKey = process.env.AUTH_SECRET;

interface IIsAuth extends Request {
  userId?: string;
  userRole?: string;
}

const checkAuth = (req: IIsAuth, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const token = (req.headers.authorization || "").replace(/Bearer\s?/, "");
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecretKey) as { UserInfo: { _id: string, role: string }  };
    req.userId = decodedToken.UserInfo._id; 
    req.userRole = decodedToken.UserInfo.role; 
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error authenticating user:", error);
    res.status(403).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
  }
};

export default checkAuth;

I want to have a token in the session object or how to add it correctly to requests in headers
Creating a JWT on the server is probably not the right approach because NExt Auth has to do it itself

JWT Helper
Maybe what you need is this, instead of using jsonwebtoken
